# Can't ping to OpenBSD router's globally routable IPv6 addresses

Tags: routing, openbsd, ipv6, pf

My router's IP address layout is as follows, anonymized to protect my network's privacy:

```
11.22.33.44                             IPv4 WAN address
192.168.42.1                            IPv4 LAN address
2001:db8:aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff  IPv6 IA_NA address on egress
2001:db8:cccc:cccc::1                   IPv6 IA_PD address on same interface as remote host
fdaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa::1                  IPv6 ULA on same interface
fdaa:aaaa:aaaa:bbbb::1                  IPv6 ULA on different interface
```

Of these addresses, all of these are pingable from a remote host on the network except for the two global (DHCPv6 IA_NA and IA_PD) addresses. The remote host has a private IPv4 address as well as IPv6 addresses from both the prefix delegation (which my ISP unfortunately limits to /64) and the ULA with subnet ID `aaaa`, and it can reach publicly-routable addresses outside of the network just fine. How does it happen that the router's ULA address is reachable but the prefix-delegated address isn't? My `pf.conf` is as follows (largely based on https://lipidity.com/openbsd/router/#pf):

```
table <martians> { 0.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 169.254.0.0/16      \
                   172.16.0.0/12 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 224.0.0.0/3  \
                   192.168.0.0/16 198.18.0.0/15 198.51.100.0/24         \
                   203.0.113.0/24 100.64.0.0/10 192.88.99.0/24          \
                   255.255.255.255/32 ::/128 ::/96 ::1/128              \
                   ::ffff:0:0/96 100::/64 2001:10::/28 2001:2::/48      \
                   2001:db8::/32 3ffe::/16 fec0::/10 fc00::/7 }

set block-policy drop
set loginterface egress
set skip on lo

match in all scrub (no-df random-id max-mss 1440)
match out on egress inet from !(egress:network) to any nat-to (egress:0)

antispoof quick for { egress lan }
block in quick on egress from <martians> to any
block return out quick on egress from any to <martians>
block all

pass out quick
pass in on lan

pass in on lan inet6 from any to 64:ff9b::/96 af-to inet from (egress:0)
# above was me experimenting with NAT64. it worked at one point, now it's not. could it be related?

pass in on egress inet proto icmp all icmp-type echoreq
pass in on egress inet6 proto icmp6 all icmp6-type { echoreq routeradv neighbrsol neighbradv }

pass in on egress proto tcp from any to (egress) port ssh
pass in on egress proto { tcp udp } from any to (egress) port domain
pass in on egress proto tcp from any to (egress) port smtp

pass in on egress inet6 proto udp \
        from fe80::/10 port dhcpv6-server \
        to fe80::/10 port dhcpv6-client \
        no state
```

Comment: 1) Is the router receiving the ICMPv6 Echo Request packets? 2) Is it sending out responses? 3) Is it sending out responses through the correct interface? 4) If it's _not_ receiving ICMPv6 Echo Requests – is it at least receiving Neighbor Solicitation packets for its address? 5) If it's not sending out responses, does it have the destination (or the gateway) in its NDP neighbour cache?

Comment: @user1686 Running various `tcpdump`s showed that it was receiving echo requests on the LAN interface and replying on the egress interface, but it was responding to neighbor solicitations on the correct interface. `ndp -a | grep "<remote host mac>"` on the router showed the remote host's ULA and link-local addresses, but not the prefix delegation. `ip -6 neighbor` on the remote host showed the router's ULA, prefix delegation, and link-local addresses.